# How to uninstall AMD drivers and install mesa? - 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, amd-graphics, mesa, amdgpu-pro

I just installed the amdgpu-pro drivers from AMD's official website.
But now some apps are not working that well and I heard that Mesa drivers were superior.

How do I uninstall these drivers and replace them with Mesa?

I downloaded the drivers from: https://www.amd.com/en/support

Followed the following steps:

1. `tar -xJvf amdgpu-pro_*.tar.xz`
2. `cd amdgpu-pro-XX.XX-XXXXXX`
3. `./amdgpu-pro-install -y`

Comment: How you uninstall something depends entirely upon how you installed in the first place. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1170795/edit) your question to clearly describe how you installed apdgpu-pro drivers. If you followed instructions, a link to those instructions would be very helpful.

Comment: Just updated it!

Comment: Look inside that .tar.xz file (or inside that directory you created from it) for a README or INSTALL file. One of those files should include both install *and* uninstall instructions - that's the standard for those files.

Comment: Ok, just found the instructions, now how can i install mesa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Mesa" is not separate from AMDGPU. The fully open source drivers are already installed in the system. Simply uninstalling *amdgpu-pro* by following the directions in its package, and rebooting should get you back to the open source only stack.

RE: Mesa, the Pro drivers simply update some components of the open source AMD driver stack, while adding a few still proprietary parts on top. You are still using Mesa with the Pro drivers.